# get the value of a php variable in an input using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to concatenate the value of my variable $variable with the value of my input using javascirpt

```
$variable= file_get_contents('./env.txt');

<select id="customer_id" name="customer_id" w300 required pj-chosen" data-msg-required="<?php __('lblFieldRequired');?>" onchange="document.getElementById('title').value=this.value + 'P' + **$variable**">
...
                    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" class="pj-form-field w400 required" data-msg-required="<?php __('lblFieldRequired');?>" data-msg-remote="<?php __('lblTitleUsed');?>"  value=""><script></script>
```

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Answer (score 2):

Ok so why not [echo](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) out the variable?

PHP:

```
onchange="document.getElementById('title').value=this.value + 'P' + '<?php echo addslashes($variable) ?>'">
```

The [addslashes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) call will escape quotes against security problems.

If `$variable` does not change a more elegant way is to make the `$variable` a JavaScript variable and then use it normally. This makes the JavaScript part more readable, but of course other programmers will have to be aware that you add that variable via PHP.

PHP:

```
// somewhere at the beginning of your body tag:
<script>
  window.variable = '<?php echo addslashes($variable) ?>';
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<... onchange="document.getElementById('title').value=this.value + 'P' + window.variable" />
```

I wrote this off the top of my head - please tell if this worked as I intended.

Answer (score 1):

On the line below you've already got some PHP inline in the HTML, outputting values into those data attributes.

For `$variable` you can follow much the same pattern as that, except you'll need to explicitly echo the variable so it gets embedded into the JavaScript (I assume those other functions echo within them, removing the need for another one):

```
onchange="document.getElementById('title').value=this.value + 'P' + '<?php echo addslashes($variable); ?>'"
```

Comment: You forgot single quotes before and after the echo. Also better use `addslashes()`.

Comment: @PeterKrebs corrected thanks. Act in haste, repent at leisure lol

Comment: Thank you, when i try onchange="document.getElementById('title').value=this.value + 'P' + '<?php echo $variable; ?>' "> nothing appears in the input

Comment: when i try window.variable i have undefined concatenated to the values

Comment: @Betty then presumably `$variable` is empty to begin with

Comment: i tried onchange="document.getElementById('title').value=this.value + 'P' + <?php echo $variable; ?> ">and it works. I removed  single quotes

Comment: Strange, that was my original suggestion. What exactly is the content of `$variable` in your test?

Comment: a simple number 006

Comment: In that case the code I provided outputs what you'd expect - demo: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/679aa2b26988f54545624d4e5daac9ccc5edc081 . If we then plug that output into a simple HTML scenario it works correctly - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/rkLeuvy3/ . So it's unclear, based on what you've said, why you would have a problem. The code should work. If it doesn't, then something (code, or data, or both) isn't exactly as you're claiming in your own version. Maybe you have another separate bug which was preventing it from working as intended?